# Best option to flatten and transform a nested array in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, flatten

I want to convert 1 complex model class into a simple model class in my project. Complex model class sample is as follows.

```
Books (id, title,content)
Content (texts[],photos[])
Photo(item)
Item (url)
Text(subTexts[])
SubText(value,style)
```

Now I want to convert it to a simpler model as follows.

```
Books(id, title,components[])
Components(UIText[],photoUrls[])
UIText(text,style)
```

Currently to flatten the text section, it is done as follows

```
fun getTexts(texts: List<Text>?): List<UIText> {
        val uiTexts: MutableList<UIText> = mutableListOf()
        texts?.map { it.subTexts?.map { realText -> uiTexts.add(UIText(text = realText.text, style = realText.style)) } }
        return uiTexts
    }
```

How can I optimize this logic?